# Expanding Static Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to extend a static array in C?

I tried creating a function which allocates a new dynamic array, copies contents to it and returns it's pointer; but It didn't work correctly, I'm getting debug error everytime.

I need to do something like this;

```
int a1[5] = { 1,2,5,4,1 };
extend(a1); //or  a1* = extend(a1);
.
.
.
a1[9] = 2;
```

My extend function so far;

```
int extend(int x[], int oldSize, int newSize) {
    int *extendedX = (int*)calloc(newSize, sizeof(int));

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < oldSize;i++) {
        extendedX[i] = x[i];
    }

    for (; i < newSize; i++) {
        extendedX[i] = 0;
    }

    return *extendedX;
}
```

Comment: no, it's not. They are `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend static array.

you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *extends(int ar[],int oldsz,int newsz){
    int *newAr = malloc(newsz*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < oldsz;i++){
        newAr[i] = ar[i];
    }
    return newAr;
}
int main(void) {
    int i,a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *a1 = extends(a,5,10);
    a1[5] = 6;
    a1[6] = 7;
    a1[7] = 8;
    a1[8] = 9;
    a1[9] = 10;
    a1[10] = 11;
    a1[11] = 12;
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)printf("%d ",a1[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this code know it can assign up to a1[11]? I suggest passing additional parameter `int newsz`, and doing `int *newAr = malloc(sizeof(int)*newsz);`.

Comment: Why do you need to move out the modification out of `extend()` - the original looks much better. He only need to change the return type to `int *`

Comment: also, it's better to leave out the array size when initialization: `int i,a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Answer (score 2):

> extend(a1); //or  a1* = extend(a1);

Your function `extend` needs to return `int *` instead of just `int`.

```
int* extend(int x[], int oldSize, int newSize);
```

Also, you need to create a new pointer `a2` to be assigned to the return value of `extend` function:

```
int *a2 = extend( a1, oldSize, newSize );
```

Comment: but I need to keep working with same variable name, a1.

Comment: No, so that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend a static array, it's size is determined at compile time.

However, you could declare `a1` as a pointer, and use a static initializer to set the initial value,

```
int *a1 = (int[]){ 1, 2, 5, 4, 1};
```

then later assign the result of the `extend` function (which should return an `int *` like @artm suggested).